# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: magento-1.9, login, ajax

In Ajax call it always gives

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://misfitlondon.co.uk/rubymage/default/login/. Request header field X-Prototype-Version is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Before 1 hour it does work fine https://misfitlondon.co.uk. Have any one idea why this happening.

I did'nt change any code in any file except styles.css.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you're trying to do an Ajax request from a HTTPS to a HTTP URL, but looking at the error log this is not the case. Did you make any other changes (for example server settings?). It could be that the server and JS headers don't match.

More info here:

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in jquery ajax in magento site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17423/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-jquery-ajax-in-magento-site?rq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232130/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr

Comment: I have just changed the unsecured base url from https://www.misfitlondon.co.uk/  to https://misfitlondon.co.uk/, now its working fine.